# Implement a dynamic logic layer to order a query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, nosql

Here I'm just looking for opinions and posible technologies recomendations which can meet my requeriments, that's why I will be using pseudo-code.

**What I need** is to implement a layer that allows me to order on the fly a complex query which can return a lot of rows.

**What I have** is a MySQL DB of users which are ordered by a field 'RANK', this field is an integer that recalculates every time that the user updates his data (asynchronously via observer pattern), in a way it is the 'value' of the user, which takes into account a lot of related tables and information of the user.

pseudo-code example:

```
if (user.meetARequeriments()) rank += REQUERIMENTA_VALUE // 10
if (user.meetBRequeriments()) rank += REQUERIMENTB_VALUE // 20
if (user.meetCRequeriments()) rank += REQUERIMENTC_VALUE // 15
...
```

The logic that checks if the user meet X requeriments can take N querys like 'where IN' and so.

All the needed calculations could take up to 2s/per user, thats why it is parsed on a queue asynchronously

This field allows me to perform a query with N conditions (which can include N related tables) without caring about the numbers of results, cause I will just order by RANK on my DB engine and I will be able to paginate the query without problem.

**What I want** is to be able to order the query on the fly, allowing me to have a dynamic RANK instead of a generic one, meaning that I could have variables instead of constants, those variables depending on a serie of preferences of the client that performs the search.

pseudo-code example:

```
if (user.meetARequeriments()) rank += getPersonalizedRequerimentAValue() // 12
if (user.meetBRequeriments()) rank += getPersonalizedRequerimentBValue() // 15
if (user.meetCRequeriments()) rank += getPersonalizedRequerimentCValue() // 20
...
```

The thing is that in order to perform this dynamic RANK assignment in my application layer, I would have to fetch ALL the results and then iterate n times to set the corresponding value (non-viable as it would take hours) so that I can return the results ordenated by this new generated RANK based on the preferences of the client(can't gain performance by pagination).

**The solution** that comes to my mind is to try to move all the logic of my application that calculates the RANK directly to the query(with subquerys), but I don't know if this will be worth to even try on a MySQL DB(if it even means any performance gain) or I should move to another DB technology to be able to perform those complex operations.

Please, ask me for further information if needed, or to clarify something. Every opinion/tip is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "could take up to 2s" - For one user or all users?

Comment: for a single user, when the user updates his data, only his rank gets recalculated. The truth is that it takes about 500ms, but it is ment to grow a lot in the short term so...

Comment: If the rank calculation can be done within one query, you could also do it in some kind of subquery and order the result by the calculated column. But the rank must be calculated for every user on every call. So with only 100 users in your DB you would wait at least 50 seconds. And paginating won't help you.

Comment: Hi Paul, the problem is that it cant be done in one query, cause most of the calculations are checks on relation-existence (where in/exists).

Comment: The query may be as complex as you want (with joins, nested subqueries,  multiple exists statemens and what ever). You still can put it in a subquery.

Comment: But would it be a significant performance gain to move multiple query calls to a query with those querys as subquerys inside?

Comment: Probably not at all. My Point is that you can write and run such a query. I never wrote, that it would be effitient. So if you want it to run fast, you will need to improve the rank calculating algorithm. I think 500 msec per user is somehow much. Possible, that you just need some indexes, to get the time under 1 msec.